# Magento 2.2 Catalog Price Rule Wont Apply

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalog-price-rules

I am using Magento 2.2. I have set Catalog Price Rule. I have saved and applied for all.  I have cleared the cache. I have also Reindex all Magento 2 indexers using below commands:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

and

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

shows Ready for all Indexes. and yet the discounts don't apply.

Comment: Can you post the rule conditions?

Comment: If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is  32, 62, 73, 21, 64, 70

Apply : Apply as a percentage of original
 Discount Amount : 20.0000
 Discard subsequent rules : Yes

Comment: You should change **`Category is`** to **`Category is one of`**. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Arora. That did not work. I changed it to `Category is one of` , cleared cache, Reindex but still no result

Comment: These conditions work fine because these are the part of the sample data of default Magento 2. I have tested in my localhost and found it working.

Comment: Both conditions have always worked fine for me too. I have used it several times. it just stopped working yesterday. i have not done any changes to the site and that is why i am really confuse as to what the problem is. It worked fine in the past.

Comment: Have you updated Magento?

Comment: No. I have not touched anything since May after developing it. and i have been using it fine and Catalog rule have always worked fine. I have not updated anything. I am using Magento 2.2.1

Comment: I am experiencing this issue on Magento 2.2.6.  I've realized that my indexing process on my server starts, but never actually does anything.  I don't know what to do either.  On my local machine the reindex command instantly recalculates prices and populates the database.

Comment: Ok, i figured it out, its silly actually.  In the Customer Group, press control and select all of them.